# Can any method crawl Quora without selenium?

Tags: python, ajax, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm new to web-crawling. I want to crawl all the answers from Quora (e.g, https://www.quora.com/Would-you-rather-get-4000-a-week-for-the-rest-of-your-life-or-3-000-000-right-now).
I think the website is loaded though Ajax (correct me if I'm wrong), and the website needs to scroll down to see more content.

My problem:
I can scrape the whole content through Selenium, but it is relatively slow. When I try to use `requests.post` method to crawl the ajax request URL, it always returns `400 Bad Request`. However, if I just use `requests.get` the webpage URL, it works and returns some content (only 2 answers).

I think it might because my request.post method is not correct, but I feel like the website has some anti-crawling secheme that rejected all requests for Ajax. I will be grateful if someone can tell me which parts I made is wrong.

This is my code

```
data = {
  "queryName": "QuestionAnswerPagedListQuery",
  "variables": {
    "qid": 1053272,
    "first": 9,
    "after": "3",
    "adsData": "{\"answer_intervals\": [], \"ads\": []}",
  },
  "extensions": {
    "hash": "c22beefa56a7d64ed1e67d4079189d089784a757b3495886f24f738e13a9af59"
  }
}


headers = {
        "cookie": 'xxx',
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Accept-Language": "zh-CN,zh-TW;q=0.9,zh-HK;q=0.8,zh;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.5",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "User-Agent": "xxx"
}


post_url = 'https://www.quora.com/graphql/gql_para_POST?q=QuestionAnswerPagedListQuery'
response = requests.post(url=post_url,json=data,headers=headers,proxies = proxies)
url = 'https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-weight-loss-diet'
get_response = requests.get(url=url,headers=headers,proxies = proxies)
```